# How to save a variable value from android app into a txt file on PC

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I need to read a string's value from my android application and write it into a txt file onto my PC, which will be read and used by an application running on my PC in parallel. The phone is connected to the PC using its USB cable, but if there's any other way.. I am open to suggestions.
The writing needs to be done recursively everytime the string changes and replace the existing string in the text file.

I have researched about adb and how I can use it for debugging and getting logs, but I do not know if it's possible to save only a variable's value.

Any method or suggestion is welcome, especially if it's simple and does the job.

Thank you.

Edit:
I'll add some details so you guys can understand my problem.
This is about my final year's project, I have to use voice command on a simulated robot in CoppeliaSim, a robot simulator.

I have developed the word recognition part using Google's Cloud Speech-to-Text API, it's running perfectly and at the end of the process I have a String containing the robot command, like "Move Up 50", "Rotate Left 20", which the simulator will be programmed to understand them as movement commands.

Now the problem is, how do I get the String into my PC and into the simulator? I have two options: CoppeliaSim provides me functions to read/write from serial port, but from all the research I have done, transmitting data from phone to PC is a big headache, plus I'd need some sort of USB to Serial port adapter.

Then I found a workaround, CoppeliaSim can read from text files that are present on my PC. If I could somehow use adb or any method to write the String into a file, I could do a repeating read from the file, thus transmitting the command to the simulator.

I ask you guys for help or any suggestions that can aid me into my problem.
For what code I have, it's just an example voice command app made by google that I modified, that after connecting to Google servers, doing some json packaging, returning a string and adding it to a list of strings that were previously identified, does nothing else.
I'm attaching the repository, if it helps: https://github.com/Hardstrike/Licenta

The weird function in MainActivity called Mutare is just for demo purposes, it moves a small car image on the screen by decoding the string. This is how the program will work in the simulator.

I hope someone can help me with any suggestions :) Thank you

Comment: No one can help you here, you have to respect "asking question rules". 
1) Summarize your problem 2) Describe what you have tried 3) Show some code. 
This is how we can help.

Comment: Added some more details to the post. Thank you

Comment: You'll need some BT/WiFi dongle in order to use it with your desktop.

Comment: I cant get any of those in time though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I came back just to tell you that I've managed to make it work. I've abandoned the idea of using a Watcher and now I only use a Timer to periodically read from the file. After some string processing, I can get the exact spoken words in a file. Thank you for the help and I wish you good fortune :)